# Как правильно настроить кнопку, для отображения вложенных таблиц?

Tags: html, циклы, vue.js, frontend, button

Всем привет. Вывожу через template vue компонента две таблицы. 
Одна вложена в другую.
при нажатии на дату в верхней таблице, должна отображаться вложенная в нее, той же даты. 
Но к сожалению никак не могу понять, как связать кнопку с конкретным значением, ибо при нажатии на любую из них, открываются вообще все вложенные таблицы во всех датах.
Очень прошу подсказать, как сделать правильно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку открывалась именно только конкретная дата.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div v-for="column in orders">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
          
            <tr class="table-active">
              <th>Дата</th>
              <th>Отменено</th>
              <th>В резерве</th>
              <th>Выдано</th>
              <th>Всего</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" v-on:click="showValues = !showValues">{{column.orderdate}}</button></td>
              <td>{{column.cancelled}}</td>
              <td>{{column.reserved}}</td>
              <td>{{column.delivered}}</td>
              <td>{{column.ordersumm}}</td>
            </tr>

          </table>
            
          <div >
          <template v-for="item in column.ordersperdate" v-if="showValues">  
            <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Заказ №</th>
                      <th>ID Магазина</th>
                      <th style="width: 180px;">Статус</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  
                    <tr >
                      <td>{{item.orderid}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.storeid}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.status}}</td>
                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Подробности</button></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            </template> 
         </div>     
      </div>
```

Comment: Сделайте минимально **воспроизводимый** пример в сниппете, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать отдельную переменную для хранения номера строки, которую надо развернуть.

При выводе таблицы проверять, совпадает ли ее номер со значением переменной.

При нажатии на кнопку указывать текущий номер.